# Javascript window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to make the shape resize when you change or stretch the browser window, but some how my shape wont appear. help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>

        <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .circle {
            border-radius: 1000px;
            background-color: rgb(0, 162, 232);
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class = "circle"></div>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var h = $("body").height();
                $(".circle").height(h / 2);
                $(".circle").width(h / 2);
            }
            myFunction();
            window.onresize = myFunction;
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you don't add the jquery lib

```
<head>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I think this article can be useful for you: https://blog.udemy.com/jquery-vs-javascript/

Comment: border-radius:50%; will suit you better ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$("body").height()` is not the height of the window. It is the height of the `<body>` element, whose height is determined by the height of the contents of the page.

What you probably want is `$(window).height()`.

Comment: notice this style in his code:       html, body {  height: 100%; }

Answer (score 0):

you can use only javascript here.no jQuery needed.

```
var h = screen.height;
var w = screen.width;
```